# how to compare number of message appears on UI with data i iterate from excel sheet (katalon)

Tags: mobile, katalon-studio

I need help verifying the number of messages on UI with data on an excel provided by me?

**Data on an excel sheet example:**

message1; message2.

**code :**

```
String[] msgs = Expected.split(';')
```

I still try to get number of message from UI first

Answer (score 0):

Our team suggests that you can use **storeText** to store messages from UI, then just use script in Java to add the logic of comparing.